# Which CPU core will os.fork() run the child process on?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, multiprocessing, fork

I recently learnt about how to use `os.fork()` and that it is the underlying idea behind multiprocessing.

From what I understand, this is the only way to make use of multiple cores when using Python because if I thread, the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) will prevent me from making use of those CPU cores by forcing only one thread to run at a time.

The thing I don't understand is how can I be sure that the new process created by `os.fork()` can somehow be guaranteed to run on another CPU core than the parent process? Or is this concern not relevant somehow?

Comment: You'll get whatever core the OS gives you.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is there any way to guarantee that the forked processes get distributed evenly among all CPU cores or do you just fork and hope for the best?

Comment: Which version of python you are using? What about the version of the linux OS?

Comment: Trust the operating system's scheduler. It knows more about this than you do.

Comment: @AnthonyKong I am running Python 3.7 on Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: @Chris So to know more about how this is done, I have to read about how the scheduler works, right?

Comment: @PeterEmil, what's your goal here? You don't have to understand the details of the scheduler simply to use `os.fork()`.

Comment: @Chris I have no current goal I am trying to achieve, I am simply trying to increase my own understanding of how things work internally.

Comment: Then feel free to read about schedulers. Some are open source, but if you're on macOS yours probably isn't. If it is, it will probably be in Darwin. This is very off-topic here, but good luck.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have been working on deep learning with python and I have found that python is completely unsuitable for scientific computing. Back to your question, python on linux uses fork by default for multiple processes, but according to my experiments, on a machine with 32 logical cpus,fork mode will always only use 2 logical cores. No matter how many workers you run. When you switch to spawn, everything changes, all the cores are running. However, spawn has a lot of limitations. In terms of parallel computing, python is a mess

Update: it's a [bug](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/99625) of pytorch. Even such a famous library can't be completely trusted.